# How to add hotkey handler with python on mac?

Tags: python, macos, keyboard, pynput

I'm using macos Mojave10.14 and python3.7.4
I've tried to add hotkey handler with following code.
But failed.
First code is.

```
import keyboard
import time
def g_hotkey_process():
    print('g pressed!')
def main():
    print('hello keyboard!!')
    keyboard.add_hotkey('g', g_hotkey_process)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() 
    while(True):
        print('...') 
        time.sleep(3)
```

And second code is.

```
from pynput import keyboard

print('hello key!dfsdf')
def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Both of two case , can,t capture keypress.
Above samples working well on windows.
Who can know this solution?